# C# MSWinsock Library Sockets - Can't connect

Tags: c#, winsock

I'm creating a C# app with MSWinsock Library Sockets. I setup everything correct (I'm 80% sure) but everytime my shockwave/flash player says there's no connection.

```
class Program
{
    static Winsock[] winsock;
    static int currentId;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        winsock = new Winsock[10000];

        winsock[0] = new Winsock();
        winsock[0].Bind(1232, "127.0.0.1");
        winsock[0].Listen();
        winsock[0].ConnectionRequest += new DMSWinsockControlEvents_ConnectionRequestEventHandler(Program_ConnectionRequest);

        currentId = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("MSWinsock server online, port {0}!", winsock[0].LocalPort);

        while (true) Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Program_ConnectionRequest(int requestID)
    {
        winsock[currentId] = winsock[0];
        winsock[currentId].Accept(requestID);

        Console.WriteLine("New connection from {0}!", winsock[currentId].RemoteHost);

        currentId++;
    }
}
```

This method is like I did it in VB6. I don't want to use System.Net.Sockets since I want to use Winsock (for change).

What am I doing wrong? I'm curious why it says it can't connect to IP 127.0.0.1 and port 1232.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies here: *winsock[0].Bind(1232, "127.0.0.1");* It looks like you only access connections from 127.0.0.1.

Try use: 0.0.0.0 instead.  *IPAddress.Any*

---

I never done socketlistening with winsock, I made an asynchronous example with `Socket` here:
http://csharp.vanlangen.biz/network-programming/async-sockets/easysocketlistener/

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. IPAddress.Any is an unsupported type, and 0.0.0.0 gives the same result as 127.0.0.1. Also, 127.0.0.1 should work as I run it on 127.0.0.1, on my own PC.

Comment: if the winsock[0].Listen(); didn't fail, is there maybee a firewall problem? I made an Easy Socket listener which will handle accepts asychonously. (Done with Socket see update)

Comment: I know how Socket class works. But it's getting bored doing the same things everytime, so I wanted to do something different this time. I've never had problems in VB6. And no, my firewall is off so it's not that.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the port is already in use

```
var properties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
var used =
    properties.GetActiveTcpListeners().Select(tcp => tcp.Port)
    .Concat(properties.GetActiveTcpConnections().Select(tcp => tcp.LocalEndPoint.Port))
    .Any(port => port == 1232);
```

Comment: Output:

The port 1232, used: False.

So it's not in use before using it in the Winsock instance.

Comment: If you already have a client connection is successful, maybe backlog is too small.

Answer (score 0):

in this part of code you forgot one line:

```
  static void Program_ConnectionRequest(int requestID)
{
    winsock[currentId] = winsock[0];

    if(winsock[currentId].CtlState!=0) winsock[currentId].Close(); //Forgotten row

    winsock[currentId].Accept(requestID);

    Console.WriteLine("New connection from {0}!", winsock[currentId].RemoteHost);

    currentId++;
}
```